# How to bind JBoss process to a particular post instead of random ports?

Tags: java, jboss5.x

I am using JBoss. The JBoss process binds to ports in a range. My application ran into troubles when setting up remote swing clients with a firewall in between server and client. I want the ability to limit the process to a particular port so I do not have to open as many ports in the firewall.

```
  I want to bind JBoss process to a particular port instead of using a range of ports.
```

I configured the serverBindPort in  server\xxx\deploy\remoting-jboss-beans.xml to 32444.
After this change it looks like Jboss is binding to this port each time server is restarted. But for some reason, it still tries to bind to random port in addition to this.

Are there any other files I need to modify?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

JBoss as a container provides a lot of services and some of these services need to bind on sockets. There are some services (like http) that bind on fixed ports while others bind on random ports.

Its easy to control the static ports but for the dynamic ports you need to know which services they are.

This [wiki](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/UsingJBossBehindAFirewall) provides all the various ports (static and dynamic). It also provides alternatives (such as HTTPInvoker) to tunnel all the requests through HTTP port.